# Path-connectedness and compactifications

Tags: general-topology

Is the compactification of a path-connected space path-connected? Why or why not?

(I came across this question in my notes while studying for finals and I have no idea.)

Comment: Are you referring to a specific compactification?

Comment: No, just generally, I mean if Y is a compact Hausdorff space and X a subset of Y and cl(X)=Y, and if X is a path-connected space, is Y necessarily a path-connected space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\Gamma = \{(x, \sin(1/x)) \mid x>0 \}$ and $X=\Gamma \cup \{0\} \times [-1,1]$. Then $\Gamma$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ and $X$ is clearly a compactification of $\Gamma$. However, $X$ is not path connected.