# Is closure of a path connected set path connected?

Tags: general-topology

It seems to me that closure of a path connected set may not be path connected. For example Topologist's sine curve  $S={(x,sin(\frac{1}{x}):0< x \le 1 }$ is path connected but it's closure is not path connected.

Am I right?...
Is there any other easy counter example?

Comment: For another example see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1005925/another-example-of-a-connected-but-non-path-connected-set?rq=1

Comment: Thanks.this example is helpful.

Comment: @AlgTop I don't see that the inclusion would **need** to be a surjection. For example, when $X=[0,1)$ (as a subspace of $\mathbb R$), the closure $\bar X=[0,1]$ is path-connected but the inclusion is not surjective.

Comment: This example is not true; the topologist's sine curve is not path connected (Munkres p.157)

Comment: For the record, this is correct and answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/446198/is-there-any-arc-connected-set-x-subset-mathbbrn-such-that-overlinex-i). To answer @Dana's comment: the topologist's sine curve is $S\cup\{(0,0)\}$, not $S$.